# Append values as a list if same key found in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am getting problem adding in new values if there is already a same key and neither can I create a new pair.

This is my code:

```
some_dirs = [
'/hosts/serverA/data/material_metal',
'/hosts/serverB/data/material_paper',
'/hosts/serverA/data/general_material',
'/hosts/users/data/testing']

some_dict = {}
for dir in some_dirs:
    server_name = dir.split('/')[2]
    if server_name.startswith('server'):
        dir_name = dir.split('/')[-1]
        some_dict[server_name] = dir_name
```

I am getting the following output:

```
{'serverA': 'general_material', 'serverB': 'material_paper'}
```

in which I am expecting the following (either 1 of the 2):

```
# Output 1
{'serverA': 'general_metal', 'serverB': 'material_paper', 'serverA': 'general_material'}
# Output 2
{'serverA': ['general_metal', 'general_material'], 'serverB': 'material_paper'}
```

Comment: `# Output 1` is not possible, dicts can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: Do you know of `collections.defaultdict`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have seen `collections.defaultdict` but have not used it very often

Answer (score 0):

```
some_dirs = [
'/hosts/serverA/data/material_metal',
'/hosts/serverB/data/material_paper',
'/hosts/serverA/data/general_material',
'/hosts/users/data/testing']
some_dict = {}
for dir in some_dirs:
    server_name = dir.split('/')[2]
    if server_name.startswith('server'):
        dir_name = dir.split('/')[-1]
        if server_name not in some_dict:
            some_dict[server_name] = [dir_name]
        else:
            some_dict[server_name].append(dir_name)
```